Why are class declarations faster than object declarations?
I have the following script benchmarking the time it takes to declare an object with a class vs. directly with an object.
console.time("class decls");
class Dog {
        a;
        constructor() {
            this.a = 1;
        }
        bark() {
            this.a + this.a;
        }
    }

for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; ++i) {
    let dog = new Dog();
    dog.bark();
}
console.timeEnd("class decls");

console.time("object decls");
for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; ++i) {
    let dog = {
        a: undefined,
        bark() {
            this.a + this.a;
        }
    }
    { // inlining the constructor
        dog.a = 1;
    }
    dog.bark();
}
console.timeEnd("object decls");

The results seem to heavily favor the first method, giving the following times when run with Bun and similar results when run with Node:
[8.46ms] class decls
[27.98ms] object decls

Why is it so much faster to declare a class and then construct a new object thereof? Is there some caching going on, or is it something else?

For one thing: you create the bark method multiple times in the second script. Not so in the first, where it is only created once, on the prototype. That is not really a fair comparison.

FYI - the difference is not as obvious in Firefox - different engines, different optimisations

Note that the way your test code is written, the runtime might figure out that it does nothing at all to the global state and therefore can be skipped entirely.

As @trincot mentioned in the comment above, the behavior you see has to do with how JavaScript engines (V8, JavaScriptCore and SpiderMonkey) optimize objects and function allocations under the hood.
Classes’ methods are put on the prototype
Meaning that when you write
class Dog {
  constructor() { /* ... */ }
  bark() { /* ... */ }
}

The bark method “lives” on  Dog.prototype, therefore it is created only once.
Every new Dog instance will refer to the same bark function
Objects create a function each time they get allocated
When you write
let dog = {
  a: undefined,
  bark() {
    this.a + this.a;
  }
}

In your code, on every iteration a new bark function gets allocated.
In terms of allocation of course this approach is more expensive, because the JIT can’t reuse the same function across all objects.
Hope this helps.

You are not doing the same thing.
When declaring a class you declare the functions once. They use the exact same memory regardless if you create 1 or 100 million objects.
When declaring it as a literal object, you create a completely new function for each object. It takes more memory.
You forgot the third option, how it was solved before class was introduced: the prototype declaration.
console.time("proto decls");

// Declaring the constructor (by convention constructors should start with an upper case letter)
function DogProto() {
  this.a = 1;
}

// Adding a function to the prototype    
DogProto.prototype.bark = function() {
  this.a + this.a;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; ++i) {
    let dog = new DogProto();
    dog.bark();
}

console.timeEnd("proto decls");

When I tested the different solutions, I got times all over the place, but the prototype solution seems to be faster most of the time in Chrome.
